# Resource loading problen in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am having a problem with my JAR file loading some graphic resources. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition) to write my code. While in the IDE, the code work fine and the resources are loaded, but once I create the JAR file, and run it, thew graphics don't show. I should mention I do have some graphics that show, as explained below:

```
package com.troymarkerenterprises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ClassTopFrame extends JPanel{

    public ClassTopFrame(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setBounds(160, 0, screenWidth-160, screenHeight/2);
        JLabel jl=new JLabel();
        jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/i_TMEA-0002-J_Logo.png"))));
        this.add(jl);
    }
}
```

This class load the image as expected. However when I try to load button images for my menu, the buttoin images do not load. Here is the class I use to create my buttons.

```
package com.troymarkerenterprises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TMButton extends JButton {
    Font okuda;
    public TMButton(String text, String color) {

        try {
            okuda = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/f_okuda.ttf")).deriveFont(16.0F);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/f_okuda.ttf")));
        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException ignored){

        }
        ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon("res/b_" + color + "_default.png");
        ImageIcon hoverIcon = new ImageIcon("res/b_" + color + "_selected.png");
        ImageIcon disabledIcon = new ImageIcon("res/b_disabled.png");
        this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setFont(okuda);
        this.setText("<html><body><br><br>"+text+"</body><html>");
        this.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.setIcon(defaultIcon);
        this.setSelectedIcon(hoverIcon);
        this.setDisabledIcon(disabledIcon);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(124,70));
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.validate();
    }
}
```

As I said, I am baffled as to why this is not working. I am not sure if my project structure is wrong, or if I am creating my JAR file incorrectly. To create the JAR file I am going to IntelliJ's project structure option  and creating an Artifact. After I build the Artifact, I set the executable bit in my systems file explorer, and run the far file.

I would appreciate any help anyone can suggest. If I have left something out in my explanation of the problem, I have my entire app post on my GitHub page at: https://github.com/troy-marker/TMEA-0002-J.

Thanks for any assistance, Troy.

Comment: does that solve your issue
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207078375-How-to-include-resource-files-in-the-jar-

Comment: In one case, you're filling the image icons with resources, and the other you're filling them with files. You should use the former method at all times

Comment: g00se, thank you. I did not realize I was doing it different. Thank you for pointing it  out to me. It is working now as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. Thank you to g00se for pointing out my error.

> In one case, you're filling the image icons with resources, and the other you're filling them with files. You should use the former method at all times

I was trying to load the graphics two different ways, and did not realize it. Thank you for the help.